# How to format a sequence value with leading zeros from 000000 to 999999?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I would like to get a sequence no. generated in the range of '`000000`' to '`999999`' which can be used by querying the particular sequence.But on creating the sequence and using it,the sequence starts with single digit `1,2,3,4...` and so on is there any way by which I could create sequence like:

*000000 ,000001,000002,000003 ....and so on uptil 999999.*

I am using `DB2 Linux x86_64` and `DB version is 10.5 FP3`

Any help with be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: Please show us what you have done to generate the sequence so far.

Comment: Do you mean a string based on a SQL sequence? Try `VARCHAR_FORMAT(yoursequence.NEXTVAL(), '000000')`

Comment: Numeric sequences with leading zeroes are "dangerous" in the sense that people often leave them off.  What are you planning to do with these?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
CHAR(DIGITS(yoursequence.NEXTVAL()))
```

which will give you a padded string representing your sequence number, something like '0000000105' for the 105th row. Then, should you need a shorter string, you can trim it with:

```
RIGHT(CHAR(DIGITS(yoursequence.NEXTVAL())),6)
```

which will give you the last 6 chars, '000105'.

Hope it helps!